# Detect/Prevent google chrome extensions of translating my web page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contenteditable

We have developed a simple WYSIWYG editor to allow users to modify their articles online, but we have faced with a problem that some users are using Chrome extensions to translate the text.

Could we detect/prevent this action using Javascript?

[image: HTML modified/transelated by chrome extensions]

I have used (`<meta name="google" content="notranslate">`) but it doesn't useful except with "Google-translate". So my issue is with other Google-extension/Google-Apps like "ImTranslator", which is able to inject HTML tags into my page

http://about.imtranslator.net/tutorials/presentations/imtranslator-for-chrome/
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imtranslator-translator-d/noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh

[image]

Comment: disable inspect element using js

Comment: Thanks, Sunil for your contribution, Really this is not the issue as we may 
disable inspect element using
"http://andrewstutorials.blogspot.com.eg/2014/03/disable-ways-to-open-inspect-element-in.html" but actually the issue in the Chrome extensions which are able to change text and also structure of HTML

Comment: You could certainly detect that the content is no longer using characters in your intended language.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is within Javascript's control.
Try adding this meta tag in your html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   .
   .
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
  <head>
```

[Meta tags that Google understands](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en)

> When we recognize that the contents of a page are not in the language
>   that the user is likely to want to read, we often provide a link to a
>   translation in the search results. In general, this gives you the
>   chance to provide your unique and compelling content to a much larger
>   group of users. However, there may be situations where this is not
>   desired. This meta tag tells Google that you don't want us to provide
>   a translation for this page.

Comment: Thank you @noogui for your comment, Actually I have used (<meta name="google" content="notranslate">) but it doesn't useful except with "Google-translate". My issue is with other Google-extension/Google-Apps like: "ImTranslator"

http://about.imtranslator.net/tutorials/presentations/imtranslator-for-chrome/
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imtranslator-translator-d/noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh

Answer (score 0):

You can mark up specific portions of your webpage and flag them as “[don’t translate this part of the page!](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html-semantic-improve-machine-translation.html)”. It’s supported by the web-based and browser-based tools from Yandex, Microsoft, Google, and Baidu.

```
<div translate="no" class="notranslate">
  […]
</div>
```

Disabling translation tools may make your tools inaccessible/incomprehensible to some users. Try to only mark up the parts that really mustn’t be translated this way and leave as much as possible free to be translated.